# Facebook LIKE button and W3C Validation Fails

Tags: css, facebook, iframe, w3c, facebook-like

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

To include the popular a [Like] button from facebook, I must use the following code :

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.MyDomain.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=225&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

My website no longer validate on W3C because of the allowTransparency attribute :

```
Line 313, Column 342: there is no attribute "allowTransparency"
… overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Is there a way around? I cannot use the XFBML version. This is pretty bad..

[Marketing et Conception Web Sherbrooke](http://www.lotusmarketing.ca/conception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried omitting this attribute? It should not be required. The standards to not even mention it.

Comment: Yup, if the button looks okay without it, it should work fine

Comment: No, not ok on a black background. The box is white.

Comment: @Etienne Dupuis: In every browser?

Comment: @Etienne Dupuis: That is because this a propietary property invented by Microsoft (@Badr Hari stated that already). If you really want your site to validate, you'll need some fancy JavaScript to add it later on (or you could add it for IE only server-side).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after going over literally hundreds of these posts, I finally found a quick and easy way to get a valid page with a Like button (or any other facebook widget) on it.

Just a fewlines of code really, take a look at http://www.liormark.com/develop/development-articles/facebook-fbml-w3c-validation-solved

Comment: You shouldn't just give a link to another site as an answer, since the site may go out of date in the future. Instead, click the "edit" link on this answer and include the essential parts of the solution from that page here. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259

Answer (score 1):

The following code should fix the validation issue:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.write('<fb:like send="true" width="600" show_faces="true"></fb:like>');
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, allowtransparency is an attribute that Microsoft made up. So use a different code with Internet Explorer family to make it work and different code for other browsers to validate?

Although it's not something you should worry about, it's a good thing to follow the standards, but if your site doesn't validate because of things like that, it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best code:

Enjoy....:)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    //]]>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    document.write('<fb:like href="URL" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>');
    // ]]>
    </script>
```